# What is the difference between 殊に and 特に?

Tags: word-choice, words

What is the difference between 殊{こと}に and 特{とく}に?

I've looked around on goo, and weblio, and [this chiebukuro question](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1219628897), but I just wanted to see if anyone had anymore further input on the difference between these two words and how they're used.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

IMO there is very little difference in what they mean but `殊に` is much more fancier than `特に`. `殊に` is almost never used in normal day to day speech, and is rarely used in written language.